# Google phrase to get to 'The Bridge'

Tags: support, chat, search

What can I type into Google in order to receive a link to '[The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge)' as one of the first few results?

'[Arqade the bridge](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=arqade%20the%20bridge&es_th=1)' doesn't even give the link to the chat in the first two pages.

'[arqade the bridge chat](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=arqade+the+bridge+chat)' does better with the link appearing in the 8th spot.

Is there any short phrase that can be Google'd to return the link as one of the first 2 or 3 results?

Comment: So... Can I ask why you'd need to accomplish this?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz so I can get to the chat easily

Comment: Isn't it easier to just type in chat.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz and then from there I'd need to click on the search bar and type in "the bridge", so much wasted time, besides I'm not going to remember that url anyway

Comment: I mean, to each their own and all, but I find your reasoning more than a bit baffling.

Comment: A bookmark would also solve the problem

Comment: @Robotnik what if it's a new computer/browser? What if it's a school or other public computer that resets bookmarks?

Comment: @Aequitas - Seeing as we're looking at indirect ways to solve the problem, put the bookmark on a flashdrive. Or even [your entire browser](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

Comment: @Robotnik the idea is for a quick simple solution to get to where I wanna go. I get that everyone will do things differently but this is my preferred method of getting to a site. I simply push ctrl+l then type in a quick phrase.   I rarely use bookmarks. usually only for things that are hard or impossible to find via search, such as my student email log in. Keyboard only navigation is generally many times faster.

Comment: @Aequitas - Ok, you've officially got me confused lol. You say that keyboard-only navigation is faster, yet you dismiss any other workaround as you want to use Google, which still requires clicks? There are 100 different ways to solve this problem, including using just the keyboard: Assuming you browse using history, you could just type 'chat', then 'down-arrow', and 'Enter'. Or you could just remember `chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge`. That's significantly faster than worrying about redirecting through Google.

Comment: @Robotnik google dosen't require clicks? yes chat down enter would be ideal, however this requires making chrome "learn" it, by going to it many times, unfortunately this won't work on new computers, also it doesn't work for me even on my home computer because I have other links suggested, after a while, yes that will be the better choice, but it requires going to the bridge via other means first. Remembering all that is 1. too hard to remember and 2. too long to type out, especially with all the special chars which are significantly slower to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just search '*the bridge chat*'. In my case, the chat room is the 1st result.

Alternatively, '*the bridge stack chat*' is a more surefire way to get the chat room.

The problem with adding the '*arqade*' keyword is, Google will search the content *on the Arqade sites* (main & meta) instead of returning the chat room directly.

*Note: this is done with Google Search, the result may vary with other search engines.*

Comment: Perfect!, thanks, who knew leaving out "arqade" would get better results! 3rd result and 1st result for me, using incognito to search on google

Answer (score 8):

I find that googling for "@wipqozn's socks" is a reliable way to get to The Bridge's transcript. From there you're just one click away from active chat!

Comment: You are my least favourite person.

Comment: [Arqade Bridge "DATA ACCEPTED"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=arqade+bridge++%22DATA+ACCEPTED%22&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&oq=arqade+bridge++%22DATA+ACCEPTED%22) has similar results :-P

Comment: [has removed Wipqozn from the list of owners of this room](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=has+removed+wipqozn+from+the+list+of+owners+of+this+room)

Comment: doesn't work anymore unfortunately.